# how to select data from hibernate list on non primary key table in which where clause data is same for all the column

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am new to hibernate framework,please provide your insight on this
I want to populate list based on the where condition,but hibernate list() returns a redundant/duplicate data in the list instead of showing all the records based on the where clause in a non primary key table in which where clause data is same for all the column

i don't have possibility to add primary key.

Below is the code snippet

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml configuration file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oracle</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>  
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="com.jspiders.app.dto.Office"/>
</session-factory>
```

This is my DTO class

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="office")
public class Office {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "column3")
    private String column3;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColumn3() {
        return column3;
    }

    public void setColumn3(String column3) {
        this.column3 = column3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Office [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", column3=" + column3 + "]";
}
```

This is my DAO class

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;

import com.jspiders.app.dto.Office;
import com.jspiders.app.util.HibernateUtil;

public class OfficeDAO {
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getUtility().getSessionFactory();

    public List<Office> retrieve() {
        Session s = factory.openSession();
        Query q = s.createQuery("select distinct o from Office o where id=1");
        List<Office> list = q.list();
        for (Office oo : list) {
            System.out.println(oo.toString());
        }
       return list;
    }
```

This is my singleton class

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final HibernateUtil util;
    private SessionFactory factory;

    static {
        util=new HibernateUtil();
    }

    private HibernateUtil()
    {
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure();
        factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    }


    public static HibernateUtil getUtility() {
        return util;
    }


    public  SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return factory;
    }


    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {

        if(factory!=null)
            factory.close();
    }


this snippet is from my main class
public static void main(String[] args) {

        OfficeDAO dao = new OfficeDAO();
        List<Office> list=dao.retrieve();

    }
```

this is my office table creation sql

```
CREATE TABLE oracle.office
(
id INT NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
column3 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

office table data

id    name  column3
1      a     qwert
1      b     abc

This is my Result

Hibernate: select distinct office0_.id as id1_0_, office0_.column3 as column2_0_, office0_.name as name3_0_ from office office0_ where office0_.id=1
Office [id=1, name=abc, column3=qwert]
Office [id=1, name=abc, column3=qwert]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your entity you are specifying `id` as `@Id`. For that to work, it has to have an unique value for each row, which is not the case in your example data. You could use a compound key for that. Have something like:

```
public class OfficePK implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id= id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Id
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //equals and hashcode
}
```

And the corresponding `Office` class would look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="office")
@IdClass(OfficePK.class)
public class Office {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "column3")
    private String column3;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColumn3() {
        return column3;
    }

    public void setColumn3(String column3) {
        this.column3 = column3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Office [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", column3=" + column3 + "]";
}
```

You could of course also include `column3` as part of the id.

And btw. you don't need to specify the column name if the name of the variable is the same as the column name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: Could you please upvote/mark as correct answer if it worked for your problem? Maybe it will help others as well :)